# Which is the popular continous integration server for the latest Magento Enterprise edition?

Tags: magento-enterprise, automation

Both Jenkins and Hudson are popular continous integration server in Java and i have worked with both. I am interested in knowing the popular CI tool for Magento. I also have the requirement to integrate source control (TFS) and testing tools (Selenium) . It would be great if the developers or architects part of this community can share the popular and  commonly used one among these or can suggest any new tool too.

Comment: This is a great example of a well-asked, important question which unfortunately is probably going to be closed for having opinion-only answers. :-(

Comment: which is a good reason to move this to a wiki page http://magento.wikia.com/wiki/Continous_Integration_Setups

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. I will try and provide an unbiased answer on all of the CI tools that I have experience with:

**Jenkins** - Provides the ability to self host the CI server and configure the build to any needs you may have. When I used Jenkins it was using the standard PHP template set to ignore the obvious paths, Core etc. It can run Selenium and I had it running Behat and PHPSpec tests.

I also enabled github hooks so that each pull request could be built prior to merging.

For me the experience was good using Jenkins. I would say that my only downsides were that the more projects I put into this build system the more maintenance I had to perform. However running the Behat PHPSpec and Static code analysis was what I needed and I could not fault the output

**Travis-ci-** Being a hosted solution there was little configuration to do other than configure the travis.yml file for tests to run analysis etc. I opted for the paid for service as they are private repos so does cost more  than Jenkins but offers the same service. Builds are nice and fast and it can still run selenium etc.

**Scrutinizer** - Again another hosted solution. Where Scrutinizer is different is that it offers more of an insight into the code by scoring the code base. This has been very helpful and also required some tweaking to remove false positives where the changes CI was putting forward did not make sense. However the tool is fast and has the same level of customisation as the others.

There are many others tools. I think Atlasan offers Bamboo that I have not experimented with yet and im sure people will be able to offer more insight into the tools they have been using and experiences.

For my open source projects I use a combination of Travis-CI and Scrutinizer but for private projects am now moving more towards Scrutinizer because of the code scoring that it offers.